# NotificationListenerService not reading text of stacked notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications

I hope this doesn't violate any rule as I've tried following the How-to-ask guide.

I'm trying to read incoming notifications using NotificationListenerService and it works for me but only partially.

The first notification of it's type, lets say - whatsapp I can get the ticker, text and title but then **if the notifications stack up I no longer can read the text of the messages.**

How do I get the text of stacked up notifications?

Here is the code I currently implement:

```
public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {

    private Context context;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
        String ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
        String title = "";
        String text = "";


        if (extras.containsKey("android.title")) {
            title = extras.getString("android.title");
        }

        if (extras.containsKey("android.text")) {
            if (extras.getCharSequence("android.text") != null) {
                text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
            }
        }
        if (pack != null) {
            Log.i("Package", pack);
        }

        if (ticker != null) {
            Log.i("ticker", ticker);
        }

        if (title != null) {
            Log.i("Title", title);
        }

        if (text != null) {
            Log.i("Text", text);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

    }


}
```

Comment: I believe this is the correct/default Android behavior. I'm looking for sources to make my point but I saw similar issues: you only read the first-on-the-stack notification.

Comment: the app airdroid for instance use the same notificationListenerService method and it reads the notifications correctly so I'm sure there is a way that i'm just not aware off

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: According to the doc. this is the correct behaviour. Just the FIRST/REMOVE notification will be notificated. <br />https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html Sorry, but i don't find any way to get updates on notifications

Answer (score 8):

If you're working with Android 7.0+, WhatsApp uses MessageStyle Expanded Notifications. Here - https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html#message-style

To retrieve all 5 messages from a notification like

```
MyFriend (5 messages)
testt
```

Do this:

```
Bundle extras = mysbn.getNotification().extras;
if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)){
        Parcelable b[] = (Parcelable[]) extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_MESSAGES);

        if(b != null){
            content = "";
            for (Parcelable tmp : b){

                Bundle msgBundle = (Bundle) tmp;
                content = content + msgBundle.getString("text") + "\n";

                /*Set<String> io = msgBundle.keySet(); // To get the keys available for this bundle*/

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if i missunderstood you, but i've a code that get's whatsapp notifications stacked and shows on logcat one by one, only problem that i'm having is that when i receive the first message, my text on logcat shows me null, and after the first, all incoming messages is working.

`public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {
        Context context;
        @Override

```
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();

    }
    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

        String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
        String ticker = "";
        if (sbn.getNotification().tickerText != null) {
            ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
        }
        Bitmap bmp;
        Bundle extras;
        byte[] byteArrayS;
        String encoded = null;

        extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
        Log.d("extras", extras.toString());

        String contato="";
        String texto = "";
        String search = "mensagens";
          if((extras.getString("android.title").toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase()))){
              if(extras.getString("android.title").toLowerCase().contains("Whatsapp".toLowerCase())){
                  extras.getString("android.title").replace("Whatsapp ","");
                  Log.d("REPLACE","REPLACE CONCLUÍDO");
              }

              if((extras.getString("android.text").toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase()))){
                  Log.d("MSG1","MENSAGEM NÃO AUTORIZADA");
              }
          }

            //TRATA AS NOTIFICAÇÕES FAZENDO COM QUE CADA MENSAGEM ENTRE DE UMA EM UMA DENTRO DA LISTA.
            if (extras.getCharSequence("android.text") != "") {
                if(extras.getString("android.summaryText")!= null) {
                    contato = extras.getString("android.title");
                    texto = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
                    Log.d("TEXTO1", texto);
                }
            }
            if(extras.getCharSequenceArray(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT_LINES) != null){

                if (extras.get("android.textLines") != null) {
                    CharSequence[] charText = (CharSequence[]) extras
                            .get("android.textLines");
                    Log.d("CHARTEXT",charText.toString());
                    if (charText.length > 0) {
                        texto = charText[charText.length - 1].toString();
                        Log.d("TEXTO2",texto);
                    }

                }
        }



        Log.i("ContatoINTENT",contato);
        if (texto != "") {
            Log.i("TextoINTENT",texto);
        }
```

`